# py2app can't import pandas

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying to create a standalone app from a python 2.7 script I have run many times and so I followed a tutorial and created the setup file that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['scrapeMaps.py']
DATA_FILES = ['export.csv']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

When I locate the scrapeMaps file (the one that was created when I did `$ python setup.py py2app -A`)  and try to run it, I get an error saying

```
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I have used pandas numerous times and it works perfectly.

I have tried adding

```
PKGS = ['pandas']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
        'packages' : PKGS,}
```

without success. Also, none of my other imports are working (if I remove import pandas, I will get an error at import selenium)

Also tried:

```
$ python setup.py py2app --packages=pandas
```

but I get a huge syntax error.

Thanks